# How to get space used by In-Memory table in SqlServer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, storage, memory-optimized-tables

I'm trying to understand how much storage In-Memory table consumes in SqlServer:

```
SELECT is_memory_optimized,durability_desc FROM sys.tables WHERE name='TBL_HSD_AD_OR'
select count(*) [#Rows] from TBL_HSD_AD_OR with(nolock)
```

[image]

Now when I'm using `EXEC sp_spaceused` I get:

```
EXEC sp_spaceused 'TBL_HSD_AD_OR'
```

[image]

Is there a different way to get the space used for Memory-Optimized tables?

Comment: [sys.dm_db_xtp_table_memory_stats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169142.aspx)?

Comment: Disregard if you have already seen this information, but I found it interesting - -https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3339/monitor-memory-consumption-for-sql-server-memory-optimized-tables/

Comment: Space used where? In memory? On disc for durability?

Comment: Total disk storage per each table

Answer (score -1):

I guess this helps you..

With the help of '**Cached Page count**' we can calculate the Total space occupied.

```
        set nocount on;
        set transaction isolation level read uncommitted;
        select
           count(*)as cached_pages_count,
           (COUNT(*) * 8.0) / 1024 AS Total_MB_Occupied, -- convert pages into MB -  the page size is 8 KB for sql server
           obj.name as objectname,
           ind.name as indexname,
           obj.index_id as indexid
        from sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors as bd
        inner join
        (
            select       object_id as objectid,
                               object_name(object_id) as name,
                               index_id,allocation_unit_id
            from sys.allocation_units as au
                inner join sys.partitions as p
                    on au.container_id = p.hobt_id
                        and (au.type = 1 or au.type = 3)
            union all
            select       object_id as objectid,
                               object_name(object_id) as name,
                               index_id,allocation_unit_id
            from sys.allocation_units as au
                inner join sys.partitions as p
                    on au.container_id = p.partition_id
                        and au.type = 2
        ) as obj
            on bd.allocation_unit_id = obj.allocation_unit_id
        left outer join sys.indexes ind 
        on  obj.objectid = ind.object_id
        and  obj.index_id = ind.index_id
        where bd.database_id = db_id()
        and bd.page_type in ('data_page', 'index_page')
        and obj.name like '%TABEL NAME%'  --- **Provide your table name**
        group by obj.name, ind.name, obj.index_id
        order by cached_pages_count desc
```

Comment: Not official. Not explained. Doesn't work.